# ORACLE: functions

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I was looking at some functions on my database and realized one of them has an red x on it, what does it mean? is there an issue with that function?

[image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The red X indicates that the database object is invalid.

```
SELECT * 
FROM user_objects 
WHERE status = 'INVALID';
```

Probably underlying table/columns have changed.

Comment: I right clicked on it and choose `compile` and the error went away, your select statement did not return anything.

Comment: _" your select statement did not return anything"_  It's hard to see the detail of the screenshot, but it appears that the object in question was listed under "other users".  The "user_objects" view only shows for the user that is connected to the session, which, by definition, would not be 'other users'.  Instead, you should have queried 'DBA_USERS'.

Comment: @DavidGarcia And if you recompiled it and the error went away then the function would no longer be invalid and would not appear on that search.